# In Android, how to create EditText of fixed width?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to create an EditText which accepts only numbers, has a  maximum of 4 numbers, and is never narrower than it would be if filled with 4 numbers (does not shrink when empty, or have to expand to accommodate 4 numbers, so it's fixed.)

The first 2 are accomplished with: android:inputType="number" and android:maxLength="4".

How can I set the minimum length?

Comment: excepts (excludes) or accepts (includes)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A little **hackish**, but you can put your `EditText` inside a `FrameLayout` alongside with another `TextView` with `text="0000"` and `visibility=invisible.`
`FrameLayout` Should have `width=wrap_content` and your `EditText` will have `width=match_parent`.
That should make it the right width always.

The advantage of this is, it's 100% xml-side, no code involved.

```
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0000"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="4" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This actually works better than kcoppock's answer, because it results in a textview of the exact right side.  But, definitely hackish.

Comment: I tried to do what Jean stated, but I couldn't for whatever reason. I ended up using hints.

Comment: In the modern age of constraint layout, this little hack can actually work quite well for fixed width numeric edit texts. You just need to constrain your EditText to the invisible TextView and there's no need for a nested layout.

Answer (score 104):

One rarely-used (AFAIK) attribute of an EditText that you can use is:

`android:ems="4"`

This makes the EditText exactly 4 ems wide. An em width is the width of the widest (M) character in the selected font.

Comment: This works, but because I'm only allowing numerical input, 4 em widths is far wider than needed. I can play around to get a better width, but it's still a bit imprecise.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I just needed a text field of a fixed length that could have anywhere between 1 and 5 digits in it and looked good regardless of how many digits the user had entered.

Comment: Maybe it's rare, but I use this frequently for my layouts when I need to achieve equal field lengths. If the font or font size changes, it adapts, unlike solutions that set unvarying lengths based on pixels.

Comment: NOTE: This disables multi-line text, instead allowing for wrapping.

Comment: And if you want to do this in java, setEms(int);

Comment: @kcoppock, may I ask you to have a look at an android question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968503/android-cannot-update-listview-on-changing-an-edittext-value ?

Answer (score 22):

In my situation, I needed the view to be 6 digits wide. android:ems made the field too wide (since the M-character is wider than a digit).

I ended up using a transparent hint which dictates the minimum width of the field. The example below is six digits wide.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="000000"
        android:textColorHint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:inputType="numberPassword" />
```

This solution is independent of font, letter spacing and other things which may vary. The textColorHint is a 0% opaque white color, so the hint should never be visible to the user.

Comment: This is the easiest solution worked best. kcoppock's solution didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

You can also try using. . .

```
android:ems="4"
android:maxEms="4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

. . . this should insure the tightest fit possibly allowed by the default android edittext style

For additional control with the padding on both left and right you can use

```
android:background="#ffffff"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use android:width="XXX.Xdp"

This lets you set the width in density pixels which ought to be relative to the screen density. I tried using ems based for a field 2 chars wide, but since ems requires a int, 2 was too small and 3 was too big. Blech.

Answer (score 1):

There is an incredibly easy way to do this programmatically.

```
myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 50));
```

This would set the width to 200 and the height to 50!!

Enjoy :)

Comment: Then of course you would manually need to see what the width of four characters would be, but I still think this is a really smooth way of manually setting width and height of an EditText!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about built-in solution but you can try passivly check the length and rise a dialog with error message at the moment of submission.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that an EditText widget can loss focus because of a lot of different actions like touching another sensitive view, menu button or (hard keyboard cursor control) and so on. The restiction of a maximum length or type of the input can be done during the tying process (accept the character if it passes the filter or the length is not exceeded). but focus lost can be occour every time - even the submission is not completed yet and the input to short -> therefore there is no build-in minimum length solution, because the application would block at this point the execution of another event or task.
At least you have to validate your input before going to the next step in your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I use android:layout_width="60dip" so agree with mike fratto.

The ems solution appears to be interesting as well.

Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can set alignment other wise when you put character more than wditText width than It's increase width or EditText width.
Please set toLeftOf and toRightOf of the above view to manage this things. Only one solution

Answer (score 0):

```
**EditText.xml**

 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/resetpage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
         <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            />

 </LinearLayout>


write this code inside the linear layout or u can customize the constraints
```

of margin in the editText as per your layout and the background is
just for the border of the editText in the **drawable** folder.

```
**border.xml**-->just paste this file in the drawable folder 

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#D0D0D0"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```