# What is android:ems attribute in Edit Text?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What means Ems? (Android TextView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053738/what-means-ems-android-textview)

In `EditText`  there is an attribute named `android:ems`. The description
is "Makes the `EditText` be exactly this many ems wide"

What does ems mean?

Comment: I am not confident to put it as an answer.. But user kcoppock's answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257843/in-android-how-to-create-edittext-of-fixed-width) thread might interest you..

Comment: same question posted here


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053738/what-means-ems-android-textview

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Taken from: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units:

> The em is simply the font size. In an element with a 2in font, 1em
>   thus means 2in. Expressing sizes, such as margins and paddings, in em
>   means they are related to the font size, and if the user has a big
>   font (e.g., on a big screen) or a small font (e.g., on a handheld
>   device), the sizes will be in proportion. Declarations such as
>   'text-indent: 1.5em' and 'margin: 1em' are extremely common in CSS.

`em` is basically CSS property for font sizes.

Comment: android:ems is the number of 'M' occurrences in a EditText field. it points to its width

Answer (score 33):

> An "em" is a typographical unit of width, the width of a wide-ish
>   letter like "m" pronounced "em". Similarly there is an "en". 
>   Similarly "en-dash" and "em-dash" for – and —

[-Tim Bray](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/-idq6Kxx5Jc/AiKN5Fe9PGAJ)

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know who this Tim is, but the only reference I could find regarding his m-width definition is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)#Incorrect_and_alternative_definitions (note the section is called incorrect definitions)

Comment: Just look him up. [Here's his Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Bray), for example.