# TextView Ellipsize (...) not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I want to have a single lined `TextView` to show up 3 dots at the end when the text is longer than the `TextView`. I don't know why - but I don't get it.

I already wrapped my head around similar StackOverflow questions, but I ended up with no solution. Maybe someone has some useful hints.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:text="Full Name" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/lName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` above is nested into 2 other `LinearLayouts`. Maybe this is important to know. I already tried the attribute "`singleLine`" too, but some say this is deprecated and it doesnt work anyway.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add the following styles in your styles file (typically `styles.xml`):

```
<style name="autoscroll">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">marquee_forever</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
</style>
```

Then add the style `@style/autoscroll` to your `TextView`:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/lName"
      style="@style/autoscroll" />
```

You can reuse your autoscroll feature easily when you want this way.

Comment: But there is no Style value for TextViews!?

Comment: use style="@style/autoscroll" instead android:style="@style/autoscroll"

Comment: how to can i use as programically

Comment: In addition to the <style ...>...</style> definition above, I had to programmatically also call setSelected(true) on the TextView in order to allow it to scroll. Without this, the TextView always behaved like android:ellipsize="end" instead of "marquee".

Answer (score 24):

Add this in your xml for the TextView:

```
        android:maxWidth="200dp" 
        android:maxLines="1"
```

As

```
        android:singleLine="true"
```

is deprecated.

Comment: Using **maxWidth** is not an *extensible* solution, and **singleLine** is now deprecated. Use **ellipsize** & **scrollHorizontally** instead.

Comment: I think there's been a misunderstanding. I just checked `TextView` at Android dev and `singleLine` is not deprecated.

Comment: I have just tried on Simulator with android 8.0.0, and `ellipsize` doesn't work without `singleLine`, even though Android Studio marks `singleLine` as deprecated! How can this happen?

Comment: You can use android:maxLines = ''1" instead of singleLine as its deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

```
android:id="@+id/lName" android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Avinljhakjhsajkhakjshda"
    android:textSize="16sp"
```

Comment: `ellipsize` is NOT deprecated. Which website do you use for reference, I just checked Android dev.

Comment: It's a mistake, I was talking about **singleLine** not **ellipsize**. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: What makes you say singleLine would be deprecated?

Comment: From the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine : This constant was deprecated in API level 3.
This attribute is deprecated. Use maxLines instead to change the layout of a static text, and use the textMultiLine flag in the inputType attribute instead for editable text views (if both singleLine and inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will override the value of singleLine).

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work with me unless adding [`'android:ems'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275348/what-is-androidems-attribute-in-edit-text) attribute along with the `android:ellipsize` attribute

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ems="8"
```

Comment: I think it's not because of setting `android:ems` specifically. If we want Android to draw ellipses, then we have to specify the length of the `TextView`, i.e. the width must not be `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 3):

The ellipses did not appear while my text was selectable.
I needed to disable selectable text (which is the default):

```
android:layout_width="0dp" (match constraint)
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with `singleLine="true"` but this attribute is now deprecated, use **ellipsize** and `scrollHorizontally="true"` instead.

Comment: You've posted it a couple of times, `ellipsize` and/or `singleLine` being deprecated. Kindly share the documentation where it says so. As I have said previously, I checked Android dev.

Comment: As I said in my post **singleLine** is deprecated since some time now, just use **ellipsize** combined with `scrollHorizontally=true`, as none of those 2 are deprecated, and it should work.

Comment: Well, here [it's not deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine(boolean)).

Comment: Yes it is because the *method* is not deprecated, no other one came to replace it as there is no reason to, but the *attribute* is. You can see it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine).

Comment: It's weird that we can use its setter while the property/attribute is deprecated.

Comment: Probably because **singleLine** is deprecated as he had been replaced by another attribute doing the same thing but in a better way. This is not the case of it's setter : if you want to access the **singleLine** attribute you still use the *setSingleLine()* function, it's hasn't been replaced by another one. But yeah anyway it's still weird !

Comment: I totally back @Flawyte on this one. I have noticed more than once AndroidStudio in canary channel displaying singleLine as 'deprecated' in xml as well. and 'maxLines' is the correct TAG to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will definitely work.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sAddress"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Adress"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this way worked for me.

I am using the constraint layout and forgot to add the constraint at the end after adding the constraints I can able to see the ellipsis at the end of the textview

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:text="asdasdnadnlaskldaklskdlasnkldsnkla"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        style="@style/TextStyle"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
```