# prevent undesired line wrapping in TextView

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

My textview is wrapping text despite the settings `lines="1"` and `ellipsise="end"`. What do I need to do in addition to prevent the line wrapping hand have the text ellipsised with a "..." as intended?

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date"
     android:background="@color/listHeaderBackground"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
     android:height="30dp"
     android:lines="1"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:paddingBottom="3dp"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="7dp"
     android:paddingTop="3dp"
     android:text="New Ion Beam Etcher ordered blah blah blah blah"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
     android:textColor="@color/listHeaderForeground" />
```

see the third item: "New sputter tool" etc. 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: **android:scrollHorizontally**: Whether the text is allowed to be wider than the view (and therefore can be scrolled horizontally). Ref. here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ascrollHorizontally

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add the following to your TextView definition:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: The global attribute resource symbol `singleLine` is deprecated.

Comment: Good catch - should now use `android:inputType="text"`

Comment: This appears to help but I get the following warning now: `Attribute android:inputType should not be used with <TextView>: Change element type to <EditText> ?`

Comment: That wouldn't be a big deal but I'm not getting the ellipsis ("...") at the end of the textView either.

Comment: Fascinating: It works when I use `android:singleLine="true"` although the fact that it's deprecated is disturbing. What I don't understand is why there is no mention of this here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine but only here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine). They tell you to use maxLines instead but as you can see that did **not** help in my case.

Comment: As of Android SDK Build-tools 21.1, `singleLine` does not warn about deprecation, whereas `inputType` does cause a warning.

Answer (score 9):

The option shown below is deprecated

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Instead use this:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

**From** [TextView Ellipsize (...) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261904/textview-ellipsize-not-working)
:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/lName"
      android:style="@style/autoscroll" />
```

And in your style.xml

```
 <style name="autoscroll">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">marquee_forever</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
</style>
```