# How to remove ellipsize(three dots) in TextInputLayout hint text?

Tags: java, android, textinputlayout

I need to remove `ellipsize`(three dots) from my hint text and want to show complete text. I am using TextInputLayout widget.

Adding `ellipsize` attribute to `TextInputEditText` does not work.

[image]

Below is the code for TextInputLayout Widget

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        layout="@layout/text_header" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/hint"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="fields"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: singleLine="true"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261904/textview-ellipsize-not-working

Comment: singleLine="true" not working

Comment: Use `android:maxLines`

Comment: android:ellipsize="end" why you are not write

Comment: I already tried android:ellipsize="end" along with android:maxLines. But it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work due to the fact that the widget is not TextView but it is TextInputLayout which is a google's material design widget

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar you are actually providing me solutions regarding TextView widget. Check my code again. I am using <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Comment: setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt arg0) try it https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText also refer dec

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar still it does not work

Comment: Actually the problem is that I want ellipsize in hint text rather textView text.

Answer (score 1):

`TextInputLayout` not showing the whole line.
 It draw the hint text and measure width from visible text character length.
 And it uses `CollapsingTextHelper` that measure the text. 
 So it is not possible to show multipleLine hint in textInput layer.

But you can show multi line hint **without using floating hint.** 
For that: set hint in your `TextInputEditText` and

set `android:hint="\n"`  int your `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Your answer is correct to much extend. But still if I set my hint in TextInputEditText, it does not fit in completely. This problem rises due to the fact that my hint is long enough.