# What can affect android:ems size?

Tags: android

I have a simple EditText with `layout_width="wrap_content"`. There are no paddings or margins in attributes. Here is a full example:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/maskPrefix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="3"
        android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/maskNum"
        android:text="GA"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
```

Everything is fine but... But:

1. When I set ems to 1, it is about 1 char wide;
2. When I set ems to 2, It is about 2.5 chars wide;
3. When I set ems to 3, It is about 4.5 chars wide;
4. When I set ems to 4, It is about 6 chars wide;
5. When I set ems to 5, It is about 10 chars wide;
6. When I set ems to 10, It is about 20 chars wide;

If I remove `android:ems` and instead set max width via `android:maxLength`, then everything is appropriate width. But I need both attributes.

Why is my `EditText` width wrong? What's with this mysterious multiplier? I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, latest android studio (2.2.2) and compile with

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
```

Testing with Android 6 in Nexus 5.

What option or attribute could mess `android:ems` so badly?

**UPD**. Link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275348/what-is-androidems-attribute-in-edit-text) does not solve my problem in any way. Also, it is absolutely correct to set both `android:textSize` and `android:ems`. I want letters of my text to be **x** sp large and I want my `EditText` to be **y** chars wide.

Comment: You are setting both `text_size` and `ems`. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275348/what-is-androidems-attribute-in-edit-text

Comment: @Chisko Yup, I set both because I need both. And your link without any explanation is pretty useless. Seems like you thought that those were values for the same purpose. Then check your own link once more ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the culprit. I thought that ems size **x** will be always the same for all characters. But I completely forgot that we have monospace and **proportional** fonts. And when we set ems to some **x**, it will be **x*y** where **y** is the width of the widest letter (usually M). But width of other letters will be smaller.
It is clear on this picture:

[image: M is wider then 1]

"M" letters is much wider then "1"!

**Solution**: we can simply switch to monospace font, like `serif-monospace`:

[image: monospace font is cool]