# Set EditText width for exact chars length

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I want my EditText for input exactly x (x=13) signs (digits) and I want it to have that width prepared from scratch. I don't want it to extend while typing or be overextended. It has to be fixed.
I read [another stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257843/in-android-how-to-create-edittext-of-fixed-width)

and used solution with setting ems=13 but then EditText is still wider (like 2x) than for 13 digits. How to solve my problem ?

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/barcode_manual_edit"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="13"
        android:maxLength="13"
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to playing with things like `android:ems`, you will need to set the `android:typeface` to be `monospace`. Otherwise, characters themselves are varying widths, and you cannot achieve "exactly x (x=13) signs (digits)".