# How do i give an editText a fixed width

Tags: android, xml

How do I give my EditText-s a fixed width. This is my code

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date:"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:textColor="#FFBBB3B9" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#c91f1f"
                android:saveEnabled="true"
                android:id="@+id/e1b"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time:"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:textColor="#FFBBB3B9" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#c91f1f"
                android:id="@+id/e1c"
                android:saveEnabled="true"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I've tried attributes 
android:maxLines and android:maxWidth but i've not been able to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: you can give width in dp or use maxEms attribute

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257843/in-android-how-to-create-edittext-of-fixed-width/4258093#4258093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fixed width of your edittext by using code:

```
EditText dittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
edittext.setMaxWidth(edittext.getWidth());
```

Comment: 'setMaxWidth' and 'getWidth' are giving cannot resolve symbol error.

Comment: Check your code.it is working fine.My solution code is tested

Comment: Avoid typing the code directly into the 'MainActivity' class. i.e make sure you write it within a method.

Answer (score 0):

In .xml file you can do it like this:

`<EditText
    ...
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    .../>`

Comment: I don't want to use a fixed width because of changes in screen sizes across devices.

Comment: dp as measure is pretty flexible. And you can use different for different orientations and screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout's android:orientation is horizontal.
You can change it to vertical.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: Great suggestion but I would like to keep the orientation as this layout is just a portion of a NestedScrollView.